# After adding CRM web service reference, Retrieve and RetrieveMultiple seem to return XlmlElement

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm working with a CRM 4 server. I created a simple console application and added a web service reference to it using the service that resides at http:///mscrmservices/2007/crmservice.asmx?WSDL

Now, according to the SDK, the service's Retrieve method should return BusinessEntity and RerieveMultiple should return BusinessEntityCollection. However, in the proxy that is created on my project, these methods return XmlElement...

What's the problem? what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code snippet that is giving you problems?

Comment: Have you added a 'service reference' or have you used the 'add web reference' in the advanced window of 'add service reference'?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I actually had to use the CRM SDK dlls and connect to the service via them. Adding a web reference didn't work as expected no matter what I tried.